# Diaglogflow account linking failed for Visual Studio Online

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have spent a lot of time lately trying to link MS VSTS account with Dialogflow. Unfortunately all my attempts failed and I am unable to find out the reason for this.

What I have done so far is:

1. Went to registered new VSO application (https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register), filling in the correct callback URI (https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/MY_PROJECT_ID) also defining the proper scopes.
2. Got back to Google's action console overview page (https://console.actions.google.com/project/MY_PROJECT_ID/overview/accounts) to fill in the details for the newly created application (authorize URL, token URL etc.) selecting Authentication Code grant type.
3. Went to Dialogflow to set the "sign in required" for the welcome intent.
4. Update the action and got the "It looks like your account is not linked yet" message in simulator, but after using the DEBUG URL to complete the process, I received "account linking failed" message for no obvious reason.

I have also tried the linking procedure with 2 other OAUTH providers and it was working flawlessly, but the MS implementation apparently is not standard.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with a lot more information. Any logs from any service would go a long way. If you could set your browser to record all network activity, particularly the ones that contain the OAuth exchanges, the parameters used in the exchanges (minus actual tokens) would be very helpful as well. Which OAuth flow are you using (implicit or auth code)?

Comment: Are these samples can help you? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples

Comment: @Prisoner: Thanks for the swift reply. I have updated my question with the type of flow - authentication code. I did't provide any trace because this issue is tremendously easy to reproduce if you have Google and MS account (and I think that there isn't a single person left out there without any of these).

Comment: Well, I'm one that doesn't have an MS account. {: And setting up the prerequisites even if one does can be time consuming.

Comment: @Prisoner: OK ... I'll go with that. There are no logs in the Simulator app and I am not sure that there are MS logs also. I was able to trace the requrests in Chrome (9MB of crap only for this communication). Here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/kng7kc8do1l5rwv/Logs.txt?dl=0) however are only the OAuth requests. Please let me know if this is what you've expected.